# If a div tag that includes php is empty, hide the div or display certain text

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

There seem to be a ton of answered questions about hiding empty divs, but after I have tried several with no luck of it working I ask my own question. I have this section on my page to display various things in this case it's titles.

**This is how it looks when there is a title to display:**

[image]

**This is how it looks when there is no title to display:**

[image]

**This is how what I want it to look like when there are no title to display:**

[image]

Below is the code part that deals with this area the question concerns, the titles are being collected after how many points a member have and are collected from functions.php, so I want something that can read that there are no title to collect from functions.php and then instead of the
ugly little square it shows *No title* if anyone has the answer to this I will be very happy, I have been on it for hours but with no success, I should say to that I am very much a novice when it comes to php and not even that when it comes to javascript and jquery.

```
 <div id='dumb'>
    <div id="assocpoint2">TITEL/S:</div><div id="assocpointprint2">
    <? if($gender === 'Mare'){echo find_asda_title($horse);}elseif($gender === 'Stallion'){echo find_asda_title($horse);}elseif($gender === 'Gelding'){echo find_asda_title($horse);} ?>
    <? if($gender === 'Mare'){echo find_asea_title($horse);}elseif($gender === 'Stallion'){echo find_asea_title($horse);}elseif($gender === 'Gelding'){echo find_asea_title($horse);} ?>
    <? if($gender === 'Mare'){echo find_asja_title($horse);}elseif($gender === 'Stallion'){echo find_asja_title($horse);}elseif($gender === 'Gelding'){echo find_asja_title($horse);} ?>
    <? if($gender === 'Mare'){echo find_sisf_title($horse);}elseif($gender === 'Stallion'){echo find_sisf_title($horse);}elseif($gender === 'Gelding'){echo find_sisf_title($horse);} ?>
    <? if($gender === 'Mare'){echo find_aspa_title($horse);}elseif($gender === 'Stallion'){echo find_aspa_title($horse);}elseif($gender === 'Gelding'){echo find_aspa_title($horse);} ?>
    <? if($gender === 'Mare'){echo find_aswa_title($horse);}elseif($gender === 'Stallion'){echo find_aswa_title($horse);}elseif($gender === 'Gelding'){echo find_aswa_title($horse);} ?>
    </div></div>
```

Comment: Just throw an else at the end to display "No Title." `<? if($gender === 'Mare'){echo find_asda_title($horse);}elseif($gender === 'Stallion'){echo find_asda_title($horse);}elseif($gender === 'Gelding'){echo find_asda_title($horse);}else{echo 'No Title';} ?>`

Comment: If I do that it returns 6 no titles, and I just want it to return one and only if the php in the div actually return completely empty

Comment: Use @MarcB's suggestion below

Answer (score 1):

Most of that code seems to be utterly pointless/repetitive. Why not something more like:

```
$output = find_asda_title($horse) . find_asea_title($horse) . etc...
if (in_array($gender, array('Mare', 'Gelding', 'Stallion')) {
   echo $output;
} else {
   echo stuff to hide the div
}
```

Comment: This unfortunately doesn't work, I wish it did, for it would be much more clean and less repetitive. But I tried it and entered all of them in the same order as you started and the only thing that did happen was that the page stopped working all together.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle the content of empty divs through css if you want:

Just target the empty div with the `:empty` selector, and add a pseudo content to it:

```
#assocpointprint2:empty:after {
   content: "No Title";
}
```

Comment: If I remove the :empty part the text No Title Shows, otherwise nothing happens. But Without the :empty it always show. Any idea why it doesn't respond to the :empty, is it because the div in fact contains several php lines alread?

Comment: No, because PHP gets processed on the server, it does not show in rendered HTML. The only way for the `:empty` selector don't work is if your div is not in fact empty!

Comment: Yes I can see that it works there but when I try to use this I come up empty handed.

Comment: @user3481279 The `:empty` selector will only match when the content is completely empty. Even whitespace in your HTML will throw it off.